# How do I use a variable with the mongo 'like' operation when comparing a number?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, mongodb-query

I have tried the same without using a separate variable search_num and use the search variable itself but the same issue persists, thats the reason I typecasted. Was tested with postman
this is my schema -

```
const lender_details = mongoose.Schema({
        lender_id : Number,
        investment_id: Number,
        name: String,
        email: String,
        mobile_no : Number,
        reg_date: Number,
        live_status: String,
        lender_details: String,
    })
```

All I'm trying to do is have a common search box, that searches through investment ID,phone and email.

```
router.post('/', async (req,res,next) => {
    search = req.body.search;

    search_num = Number(search);
    console.log({$regex : search_num});
   await a.find({
     "investment_id" :($regex : search_num),
       "email" : { $regex : search } }
    ,{ _id : false })
```

The /m/ concept does not work when using a variable and so I have used regex, but after trying almost everything this error persists when I'm trying to search the investment ID which is a number -
Cast to Number failed for value "/1/" at path "investment_id" for model "lender_details"
Any and all help appreciated !

Comment: `'/1/'` isn't a number, why are you trying to cast it to `Number(search)`…?

Comment: you do not need to provide regex to search in mongodb. just use:
` await a.find({
     "investment_id" :search_num,
       "email" : search }
    ,{ _id : false })`

Comment: Hi, the reason is I do not want to do an exact search, want to do something similar to 
 LIKE %m% in SQL, hope this answers your question

Comment: `{$regex: new RegExp(req.body.search)}`…?

Comment: @deceze the same error persists :)

Comment: It's still complaining about `Number`? Because `Number(search)` is still superfluous.

Comment: yes still the same error message, I was passing 1 in search box, the search for email works however when I comment out the investment_id search

Answer (score 0):

Iirc you should translate it firstly to string with using some search pipe then you can search it with regex;
Let me show some of example;

```
a.find({
"$expr": {
    "$regexMatch": {
       "input": {"$toString": "$investment_id"}, 
       "regex": search_num_regexp 
    }
})
```

or

iirc you can use where operator but it will maybe decrease the performance  query and i am not sure if it will work correctly. but it would something like below

```
a.find({
  $where: `${search_num_regexp}.test(this.example)`
})
```